# what do i do with throw to handle wrong data type in c++

Tags: c++, throw

so I am trying am trying to convert a integer to hexadecimal and i am placing a non int type into the input variable as well as a negative number. when i do add the throw code it flops. without the throw it will loop forever. Am i throwing the wrong throw argument? how would my if statement handle non int types such as a, b car into the num variable?

```
cout<<"please enter integer number to be converted to binary (less than 65536) "<<endl;
    cin>>num; 
if (num <=0)
{
   throw invalid_argument("wrong input");
}
else
cout << num + 1;
```

Comment: Huh?  There is no loop here.

Comment: if it's not structured input, using the stream operators is a bad choice as they fail silently

Comment: Exceptions are for exceptional situations not general error handling.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious: Try telling that to the authors of core Java ;) (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: using this page: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/operator%3E%3E/
 set an exception on the failbit for when the input could not be parsed as the type you'd expect

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I'd be better off saying happy holidays to a Republican. ;)

Answer (score 0):

If the `cin >> input` operation fails, `input` will not have a value set to it (that is, whatever value it had, it will continue to have).  You are not showing a loop in your existing code, so if you are reusing the same variable in a loop, it would loop indefinitely because after the failed extraction, the fail bit for the standard input is set and num would have whatever value it had previously.  You must clear it before attempting to read again.  The typical method for handling input errors like this is the following:

```
int num;
while (!(cin >> num))
{
    std::cout << "Please enter a valid value!" << std::endl;
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
}
```

There is no good reason to use an exception in this case, but if you did, it would look something like this:

```
int num;
if (!(cin >> num))
{
    throw std::invalid_argument("Invalid entry");
}
```

which would mean you would have to reset the standard input buffer in your catch block.